# rsync succeded, but it deleted the files I synced

Tags: rsync, data-recovery, zfs

Basically, what the title says. I ran `rsync` to sync some files in a folder to another folder and now I can't find them anywhere.

The command I ran was this:

```bash
rsync -auzRP --no-hard-links --no-links --remove-source-files Videos/ ../videos/
```

I had some garbage there which I don't care much about, but I also had some old videos of family stuff, which I'd like to recover. Is it possible? Doesn't `rsync` cache before sending? Also, I don't know if it is relevant, or helpful, but the filesystem where the transfer occurred is a `zfs` (RAIDZ2).

I have already searched online but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Was the name of your current working directory `videos`? In other words: was `../videos/` and `./` equivalent?

Comment: Both directories were in the same folder; the only difference was that one was with capital letter and the other with minuscule.

Comment: Did you check/Can you check if there is actually a directory `../videos/`? What is there now?

Comment: "Both directories were in the same folder" – `Videos/` is `./Videos`, the parent of it is `./`. The parent of `../videos/` is `../`. I'm asking if `../videos/` is in fact `./`.

Comment: @sudodus No directory called that :/

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `pwd` is `/mnt/backups/videos` under this, there were two folders: `Videos` and `videos`.

Comment: But you told `rsync` to write there :-( It is a good idea to test things first with a dry run using the option `-n`, and only when things look good remove `-n` and do the real thing.

Comment: @sudodus I've learnt that the hard way now, to say the least :|

Comment: So your command was equivalent to `rsync -auzRP … --remove-source-files Videos/ ./`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think that is correct.

Comment: If you stop using the drive as soon as possible (turn off the computer) boot from another drive and not mount the partition where you had the files, you can try to recover data from the 'drive surface' even without the pointer of the file system, when using [PhotoRec](https://cgsecurity.org), but it can be a lot of work.

Comment: @sudodus i have installed `testdisk`, which seems to contain PhotoRec. I'll see if I can find something out using that tool and following the link you posted. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck @telometto :-)

Comment: Well, my tests indicate this command effectively synces `Videos/` *to itself*, so it doesn't make a copy. And then it removes the content of the source, i.e. the *only* copy. Quite a mishap. It would be nice if the tool warned about it, but it apparently doesn't. Usually *nix tools assume you know what you're doing.

Comment: It's kind of a bummer, yeah. Well, lesson learned. I'm trying to see if `zfs` has made a snapshot somewhere, but they all have very cryptic names... they look like random hashes.

Comment: I tested this deep down in a directory tree, and in the dry run `rsync` said `created directory ../videos` (and I ran the real thing and so it did). I have rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31 (running in Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and an ext4 file system. I have not checked what would happen when rsync would not be allowed to create the target directory. I think in your case either the target directory could not be created or `rsync` didn't even try or failed but did not exit before removing the files.

Comment: No matter how cryptic the snapshot names, look at the creation dates: `zfs list -rt snap -o name,creation tank/your/fs-name/here`. Find the most recent one prior to your mishap and `ls -l /your-mountpoint/.zfs/snapshot/cryptic-snap-name/Videos/` and see what's there.

Comment: Thanks for this command. I enabled the snapshot feature *after* the mishap, which are the snapshots that are showing. Oh well... good thing that it didn't happen to the rest of my files.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you describe, the **--remove-source-files** is not a good fit for your context.

The use of that option flag is **intended for the context of "batch handover"**, and not "backup".

The destination for such cases would usually be an empty directory which is being scanned by the receiving-side host for pickup and forwarding of those files to another location, either on that receiving host or on another follow-on host.  Not quite exactly like, but similar to, a mail forwarding postal station.

The command I use in my own backup program is as follows:

[image: Backup script source showing rsync command definition]

and during execution, by the background process monitor script,

[image]

The options seen there would be worth your while looking into.